# Erro no Hibernate ao executar projeto web

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Estou com um erro que não consegui resolver, inicio meu projeto e ele roda certinho.
Quando eu acesso o projeto via web, faço o login e ele entra.
Quando eu clico em qualquer botão, ele dá esse erro abaixo:

**Hibernate:**

```sql
select
    person0_.id as id1_3_,
    person0_.accessUserName as accessUs2_3_,
    person0_.hourPay as hourPay3_3_,
    person0_.name as name4_3_,
    person0_.version as version5_3_ 
from
    Person person0_ 
where
    person0_.accessUserName=?
```

**Erro:**

> 2017-01-10 11:46:32,889 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column person0_.accessusername does not exist
>         Dica: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "person0_.access_user_name".
>         Posição: 31

Comment: Não entendi qual é a relação disso com o Spring ou com o Spring Roo. Editei o título e as tags.

Comment: Então, é que o projeto foi feito com o Spring Roo, e no cmapo "Tags" daqui do Stack  não tem essa opção hahahah, mas então, toda vez que eu starto, da esse erro, quando tento acessar alguma link da minha tela, e o erro eh esse que o campo nao existe.

Comment: Odair, é que para criar tags tem que ter um pouquinho de experiência no site, isso não é permitido a usuários recém-chegados para evitar a criação de tags ruins e tags com spam (e mesmo assim algumas dessas ainda acabam sendo criadas). Se quiser, posso adicionar as tags de [spring] e [spring-roo], mas embora o seu projeto possa utilizar o Spring Roo, isso não significa que o escopo da pergunta aborde o Spring Roo.

Comment: Qual que é o banco de dados que você utiliza? Como é feito o acesso a ele?

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de erro é bem clara - a coluna `accessusername` do seu `select` não existe, mas a coluna `access_user_name` existe.

Assim sendo, o que você tem que fazer é corrigir a sua consulta SQL corrigindo a grafia do nome dessa coluna.

Answer (score -1):

Isso acontece porque sua(s) colunas não estão mapeadas corretamente

```
@Column(name = "access_user_name")
private String accessUserName;
```

Ajuste o atributo **name** exatamente como é no banco de dados.

Também pode ter alguma política de **camel case** configurada, ativa que pode gerar esse erro de mapeamento